# probability distribution of $X=U^{-\alpha}$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $U \sim \operatorname{Unif}[0,1],$ and $\frac{1}{2}<\alpha<1 .$ Set $X=U^{-\alpha}$. What is the probability distribution of X? Is X integrable?

My attempt:
$\mathbb{P}(X \leq a) = \mathbb{P}(U^{-\alpha} \leq a)\\
 = \mathbb{P}(e^{-\alpha \ln{U}} \leq a) = \mathbb{P}(- \alpha \ln{U} \leq \ln{a}) \\
= \mathbb{P}(\ln{U} \geq - \frac{\ln{a}}{\alpha}) = \mathbb{P}(U \geq e^{- \frac{\ln{a}}{\alpha}}) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(U \leq e^{- \frac{\ln{a}}{\alpha}})\\
 = 1 - e^{- \frac{\ln{a}}{\alpha}}$

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: To show that X is integrable I have to show that $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is finite. And I've tried to find the probability distribution by using the distribution function but I got stuck

Comment: Where did you get stuck exactly? Add this to the question body

Comment: yeah sure, I posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done. Note that $U^\alpha\in(0,1)$ and so $U^{-\alpha}\in(1,\infty)$. Thus$$P(U^{-\alpha}\le a)=\begin{cases}0,&a\le1\\1-a^{-1/\alpha},&a>1\end{cases}$$differentiating which we obtain $f(a)=\frac1\alpha a^{-1/\alpha-1},a>1$. Fairly easy to observe $\Bbb E[U^{-\alpha}]=1/(1-\alpha)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @earth Sure, although I am still a bit puzzled as to where you were actually stuck. You seem to have solved it almost all the way to the end, stopping short of differentiating the distribution function to get the PDF...?

Comment: I didn’t know exactly if it was right the way I did. I tried to calculate it at the beginning with the tranfer theorem. When you asked me to write my answer in the question, I thought it over and came up with the idea of doing it thid way.:)